# Enhancing the performance from changing the bitmap to hexString

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap, hex, fileoutputstream

I am trying to convert the captured photos (in .jpeg format ) to hexadecimal strings but when it comes to action, it tales more than 2 minutes to return the successful conversion. Would you please tell me how to enhance the performance besides increasing the buffer size? (using in Android)

The below is my code

```
private String changeByteToHex(byte[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte d : a) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", d));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public String photoEncode(File file) {
    try{

        ByteArrayInputStream inStream = retrieveByteArrayInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] temp = new byte[8192];
        int read;

        while((read = inStream.read(temp)) >= 0){
            outStream.write(temp, 0, read);
        }

        byte[] data = outStream.toByteArray();  
        return changeByteToHex(data);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think there is any efficient way to do this, but I doubt you can successfully do this everytime without facing any out of memory error.

Comment: but it results in ANR

Comment: May I know why in the first place you plan to convert your photo into hex?

Comment: it is because the captured photos may be sensitive content. It must be encoded into databytes first before upload to server.

Comment: To prevent ANR you can run the above codes in AsyncTask, but converting whole image bytes into a byte array and a String object will eventually cause Out of Memory error.